# How can I get all cell value of specific column

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

[image: i am getting values in date picker.similarly how to get values in Itemc[1001] and get saved to a String object like what i have done in date picker]

```
@FXML
private DatePicker dp;

String  datepicker=dp.getValue().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);       
System.out.println("date is"+datepicker);
```

My tableview has user input values for eg.Itemc has value 1001. And all i need is to get values in the column and add that value into a String object.Above code is a sample code for date picker and am getting date entered by user at String object datepicker.Similary i should get values in tableview column.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Is column1 an editable column?

Comment: @kleopatra It's not the first time I read your comments through new questions on this page, and I am still waiting to see you write a constructive comment. Given your reputation you should try to make the community learn and grow instead of belittling their work and effort...

Comment: @AlexanderOrtiz it's the n'th question around the exact same problem with the exact same missing information/effort of learning - my patience is thinning and that thinning shows. Just saw the self-answer - could you have guessed it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
table.getItems().forEach(item -> System.out.println("Specific column value is "+item.getItemc()));
table.getItems().forEach(item -> System.out.println("Specific column value is "+item.getcategory()));
table.getItems().forEach(item -> System.out.println("Specific column value is "+item.getunitprice()));
```

Using above code am able to print values in tableview.

Comment: If you look at that answer, you will see why no one else was able to answer your question. There is too much information that is needed that was not posted in the question. For example, nowhere did you say what type of item was in your table and what properties it had. There are people here willing to help but they are not clairvoyant- you need to provide enough information for them to help you.

Comment: @James_D ok  i will be more specific !!